# Transparent LXTerminal on LXDE

Tags: linux, arch-linux, terminal, lxde, lxterminal

I've been trying to set transparent terminal background in lxterminal on Arch Linux but with no luck. Setting transparent background in preferences does nothing, so does setting transparent to 1 in lxterminal.conf. I remember it being transparent in Lubuntu 16 but I can't manage to get it on Arch. I know that it was probably fake transparency, but it's sufficient for me.

Comment: You probably need a compositor (I use compton for URxvt in i3 to get "real" transparency...the "fake" transparency has a significant delay when dragging the window around).